# Picklist values not showing but no record types are defined

Tags: picklist

Seems to be a common problem with a simple solution, but my issue seems different.

We have no record types defined, yet the new values are not showing in the picklists on accounts, leads, and contacts. The issue is with the fields AccountSource and LeadSource.

What could the issue be?

**EDIT: Moderators, please delete this thread. I don't want it muddling up the other similar questions. It was an issue where two fields had the same field names and one field was hidden**

Comment: You're going to need to tell us more. Are these global picklists? What objects are they defined on? You say you have no record types. Might that be your issue? Do you have a sales process configured? There's much you've not told us. How did you configure the picklists and what behavior did you expect?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info. I've been removed from Salesforce for a year and this used to be a simple task. No sales processes configured. Picklists are the Salesforce default ones for the Accounts, Contacts, and Lead sources. I expected to put the item into the picklist data and it would show.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any dependent lists ? If not, it is a common problem with global lists.
Ref: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000IYpqQAG

Comment: Had this issue today. Fixed by manually entering values from Global Picklist...

Answer (score 0):

By any chance picklist values are inactive? Sounds silly but could be a possible case.

if not try with following trials

- Use different profiles to test this scenario
- Try adding few more picklist values OR reset them
- Add record type and then inactivate it.

Note: If in case there was a record type and it got deleted, then you have to do same trial again & inactivate recordtype instead of delete.